# Internet adapter don't work properly with different subnet masks in a multi adapter PC

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, samba, nas

I'm having some troubles trying to config a triple internet adapter configuration in my 'home made NAS server', aka a old computer like a server, using Ubuntu desktop 22.04.4 with a SAMBA share for my Windows 11 machines.

In this computer I have the onboard ethernet (realtek) card, and cheap a PCIE (intel i226-v) with two RJ45 ports.

I'm trying to define the IP and subnet mask (like someone else suggest) to send my home DNS to the this PC onboard card, so I can use pihole to block some stuff, and I'm trying to use the PCIE like a private and offline network, with point to point connection instead of a switch.

My onboard IP is set like:

```
192.100.100.100 with a 0.0.0.0 mask
```

My first PCIE port is set like:

```
192.100.100.101 with a 255.255.255.0 mask
```

With two ports being used, this works properly and I have internet on both Windows machines with local DNS IP and a offline network accessible by IP, but when I try to define the IP and mask to the third one, the offline lan doesn't work.

I already try some different configuration but I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, or how can I test the adapter to see if there is some trouble, like a hardware problem.

Here is what my samba.conf looks like:

```
interfaces = lo 127.0.0.1 192.100.100.100/255.255.255.0 192.168.10.102/255.255.255.0
bind interfaces only = yes
```

I'm trying to ignore the default adapter so the IP and mask are booth set in the network GUI. Deleting the second IP, make things kinda works, but I need it for booth PC's.

So, there is a 'proper' way to do it, like use the third port with a different subnet, or different subnet range? Subnet thing is new for me and I'm lost.

Comment: "192.100.100.100 with a 0.0.0.0 mask": That looks wrong. Please [edit] with `ip r`. You want 3 different IPs in different subnets, then a default route going into the first one's gateway

Comment: Linux tyIpe 0.0.0.0 mask in the gnome network, I don't know why, but it was my mistake to write it. My problem is how set the IP's and subnets, like main onboard 192.100.100.100/255.255.255.0 and primary PCIE on SAMBA 192.255.255.25/255.255.255.0 or something else like 192.255.255.25/255.255.0.0 and second door should use a different subnet to or not.